# Множественный вывод изображений из свойства инфоблока типа файл

Tags: битрикс, изображения

У меня есть календарь-лента с событиями,нужно добавить возможность загружать фотографии,  сначала вместо фотографий выводилась  просто одна  иконка изображения, а теперь вообще ничего не выводится.

Код в файле result_modifier.php

```
   $arResult['GALLERY'] = [];

foreach ($arResult['PROPERTIES']['GALLERY']['VALUE'] as $fileID) {
    $arResult['GALLERY'][] = CFile::GetPath($fileID);
}
```

Код в файле template.php

```
 <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                <? foreach ($arResult['GALLERY'] as $sPicture): ?>
                        <img src="<?= $sPicture; ?>" alt="<?= $arResult['NAME']; ?>">
                <? endforeach; ?>

 </div>
```

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1):

По идее у вас всё правильно если GALLERY это свойство типа файл и множественный выбор.
И если вы добавили это свойство в свойствах настройки компонента.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я думала об этом, но дело в том, что у компонента календарь нет полноло списка настроек, и я не знаю как ему подлючить это свойство.  Я могу только настроить шаблон компонента и композитный сайт. Можно ли добавить это свойство в файле параметров компонента?

Comment: Попробуйте получить это свойство в `result_modifier.php` https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/classes/ciblockelement/getproperty.php

Answer (score 1):

**Код в файле template.php**

```php
<?foreach($arResult["MORE_PHOTOS1"] as $PHOTO):?>
        <img src="<?=$PHOTO["SRC"]?>">
<?endforeach?>
```

**Код в файле result_modifier.php**

```php
<?
$arResult["MORE_PHOTOS1"] = array();

if(isset($arResult["PROPERTIES"]["MORE_PHOTOS1"]["VALUE"]) && is_array($arResult["PROPERTIES"]["MORE_PHOTOS1"]["VALUE"]))
{
    foreach($arResult["PROPERTIES"]["MORE_PHOTOS1"]["VALUE"] as $FILE)
    {
        $FILE = CFile::GetFileArray($FILE);
        if(is_array($FILE))
            $arResult["MORE_PHOTOS1"][]=$FILE;
    }
}
?>
```

У изображения есть характеристики, такие как:

- Вес
- Название
- Путь к изображению

Вы указали переменную `$sPicture` - но не указали что именно нужно выводить - в вашем случае это `$sPicture["SRC"]`.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]